# How create and include Profile in User model (User its model devise)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

1)install user model (its gem devise)

all settings - all is ok

2) rails g scaffold Profile name:string role:string user:preferences

all settings, migration, and add in model User - has_one :profiles

3) In rails console, i dont find binding id

Were i do error?
Help pls. Me need one User, one profile before registration..

Comment: can you please format this to be readable? That's not my down vote but it's totally reasonable to down vote questions this unclear.

Comment: What are you trying in the console? What's the expected behavior? What's the actual behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rails g scaffold profile name:string role:string user:references
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is here:

```
user:preferences
```

which should be

```
user:references
```

To fix it, you can remove your scaffold with:

```
rails destroy scaffold Profile
```

and then run the command again